# Laravel Eloquent search inside related table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm having a  list of users which have multiple roles and Iwish that my ajax search method could search inside this resultset (user1 have user role and admin role).
So Iwrote my request like this :

```
$usersData = User::where('name', 'like', $queryString . '%')
        ->orWhere('email', 'like', $queryString . '%')
        ->orWhere('username', 'like', $queryString . '%')
        ->when($limit > 0 || $offset > 0, function ($usersData) use ($limit, $offset) {
            $usersData->take($limit)->skip($offset);
        })
        ->with('roles:name')->whereHas('roles',function($query) use($queryString){
            $query->where('roles.name','like',$queryString.'%');
        })
        ->get();
```

But it doesn't work have you an idea what is the problem ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `orWhereHas()` instead of `whereHas()`:

```
->orWhereHas('roles', function($query) use($queryString){
    $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $queryString. '%');
})
```

Comment: Nice it's perfect I understand why now, Thank you !