# Laravel Query Through Relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am creating a search in laravel where customers can search for vehicles.

Table 1

| Vehicle |
| --- |
| VIN |
| PLATE |
| make_and_model_id |

Table 2

| Vehicle Makes and Models |
| --- |
| id |
| make |
| model |

Relationship in Table 1: Vehicle

```php
public function vehicle_make_and_model_fk()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\VehicleMakeAndModel', 'vehicle_make_and_model_id');
}
```

So I am searching for VIN or Plate. That works fine.
I also am Searching for a Make and Model name which is a foreign key.
I pulled in the related table using **with** which works fine.
Now how to search through the columns of Make and Model Table?

```php
if($request->ajax()) {
    $search = $request->search_query;
    $vehicles = Vehicle::with('vehicle_make_and_model_fk')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
            $query->where('plate', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
                  ->orWhere('vin', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
                  ->orWhere('vehicle_make_and_models.make', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%');
        })
        ->limit(5)
        ->get();

    echo json_encode($vehicles);
    exit;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To filter the relationship, you need to use a closure in your `with()`

For example:

```php
$vehicles = Vehicle::query()
    ->with([
        'vehicle_make_and_model_fk' => function ($query) use ($search) {
            $query->where('make', 'like', "%$search%")
                  ->orWhere('model', 'like', "%$search%");
        }
    ])
    ->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
        $query->where('plate', 'like', "%$search%")
              ->orWhere('vin', 'like', "%$search%");
    })
    ->limit(5)
    ->get();
```

[Eloquent Relationships - Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

Comment: This did not work. "%$search%" that had to be changed to "%".$search."%" and still did not work. Not sure why. I read the documentation and this is how it should be, but would not work.

Comment: On further searching - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48406444/laravel-eloquent-search-inside-related-table
query from that answer helped and it worked. Posting query below as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $vehicles = Vehicle::where('plate','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
            ->orWhere('vin','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
            ->with('vehicle_make_and_model_fk')
            ->orwhereHas('vehicle_make_and_model_fk',
                function($query) use($search){
                    $query
                    ->where('vehicle_make_and_models.make','like',$search.'%')
                    ->orWhere('vehicle_make_and_models.model','LIKE','%'.$search.'%');
                }
            )
            ->limit(5)
            ->get();
```

This query worked. It would search and bring results from vehicle table and would go to makes and models table and bring results from there as well. Based on - [Laravel Eloquent search inside related table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48406444/laravel-eloquent-search-inside-related-table)